# How to get value of input saved in a state and using it outside the component after pressing Enter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making kind of a search input that, when pressing *enter*, it should be able to execute a function written in its prop `onEnter`, but I don't understand how I could approach it.

Code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { t as typy } from "typy";


export type Props = {
  name?: String,
  imgSrc?: String,
  alt?: String,
  onEnter?: function
};

export const SearchInput = ( {name, imgSrc, alt, onEnter}: Props ) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button className='input-search-mobile' onClick={typy(onEnter).safeFunction}>
        <img src={typy(imgSrc).safeString} alt={typy(alt).safeString}/>
      </button>
      <div className='input-search'>
        <img className='input-search-icon' src={ typy(imgSrc).safeString} alt={typy(alt).safeString} />
        <div className='input-search-divider'></div>
        <input type="text" name={name} onKeyPress={
          (e) => {
            if(e.key == 'Enter'){
              {onEnter(searchText)}
          }}
          } onChange={event => setSearchText(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default SearchInput;
```

Component with props:

```
<SearchInput imgSrc={lupa} onEnter={() => {*I need to get the value of searchText somehow*} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code snippet for `SearchInput`, it seems you forgot to pass the value in your `onEnter` callback function.

Try doing this: `onEnter={(val) => console.log(val)}`

Comment: That worked. Do you see any improvements I can do to my code?

Comment: Well, all your callback functions are defined inline. This **may** cause performance issues because the child component renders needlessly. In your example, Your `SearchInput` component has an onEnter callback function. Every time the parent of SearchInput re-renders, SearchInput will re-render (even if it's a PureComponent) because a new function is created. This is why defining functions inline tends to be frowned-upon. However,  "premature optimization is the root of all evil", so if this isn't causing performance issues, I wouldn't be concerned.